# why Response.Write() wouldn't work after async post (using ajax) in asp.net razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, razor

the problem is when i want to display using "response.write()" in the html document it just don't work (without any error ) ,if there any method that display async please tell me

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="test">
    username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    password: <input type="password" name="password" /> <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="send()" value="send" />
</form>
<script>
    function send() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var f = $("#test")[0];
        var fd = new FormData(f);
        xhr.open("POST", "hello.cshtml");
        xhr.send(fd);
        f.username.value = "";
        f.password.value = "";
    }
</script>
@{
    if (IsPost)
    {

        var user = Request["username"];
        var password = Request["password"];
        Response.Write("user" + user); // ????????

    }
}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add the error you received and the code that produced the error?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJPgd.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide the relevant code as a code snippet (as opposed to an image).

Comment: Could you also provide us with the error that you are trying to fix? Although this is not the preferred way to use asp.net. The postbacks and the development on the razor files is not good for the performance.
Be very careful when using the [Response.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.write?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Web_HttpResponse_Write_System_String_) method because it has security issues. (Possible XSS attacks etc.)

Comment: actually there is no errors showing up ,i m just want to write a message in the document without loading the whole page,that all what i want, i know that Response.write have some security issues, if ther any method that would help me, 
please suggest  it ,and thx .

Comment: Press F12 in browser run network trace.  What do you see on the Write?

Comment: do u mean the right ?